# paperjs: moveAbove don't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, paperjs

I have 2 Path, i use item1 move above item2

`item1.moveAbove(item2)`

it has changed the value of the index path but does not display correctly on the screen.

Item1:
[image]
Item2:
[image]

But on screen item1 still below item2.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a simple test-case, perhaps on http://sketch.paperjs.org/ ?

Are you using JavaScript directly and modifying the scene graph from a native JS event? In that case, you need to update the view manually:

```
paper.view.update();
```